# Did i miss anything from flutter google ad mob tutorial?

Tags: flutter, admob

i am trying to monitize my app using admob but its really hard to implement it in the app even with the youtube, now everything is set but it gives the following error,

here is the code

https://pastebin.com/khzvByzA

and here is the ad state

https://pastebin.com/UE7d3mmD

and this is the main code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  var appDocumentDirectory =
      await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(MonsterAdapter());

  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);


  runApp(
    Provider.value(
        value: adState,
        builder: (context, child) => MyApp()
    ),
  );
}
```

it shows error LateInitializationError: Field 'banner' has not been initialized.
on the first pastebin link

I still dont understand about late final and etc. am I miss anything ? I build it withe the tutorial, EXACT. and i have been checked the code, TWICE. and still don't know how to do this :(

by the way, here is the tutorial link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0d_pbgeeG8&t=990s